# Unused arguments in SOM function

Tags: r, neural-network, som, unused-variables, self-organizing-maps

This is my first post and I am newbie in R. I'm trying to train a Self-Organizing Map. My data is a matrix of 2304 instances with 7 features each instance ([2304x7])

Following the example codes with (like wines' dataset) I have no problem but when I try to modify some features with my data I have this error:

> Error in som(datos, grid = som_grid, init = "random", alpha = c(1,
>   0.1),  :    unused arguments (alphaType = "linear", neigh = "gaussian")

I am just typing code below:

```
library(kohonen)

som_grid<-somgrid(xdim=8, ydim=3,topo="hexagonal")

som_model <- som(my_data, grid=som_grid, init="random", alpha=c(1.0, 0.1), alphaType="linear", neigh="gaussian",r adius=c(15,3), rlen=c(100,1000))
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you so much and sorry it is answered already (I didn't find it)!

Comment: I saw that the example codes have:   set.seed(7)    before the training but I don't understand what it does.

Comment: set.seed(some number) lets you get the same result each time when there is a randomization step.  Without it, your returned values will vary each time

Comment: `alphaType` and `neigh` are options of the `som` command in the `som` package, not in the `kohonen` package.

Comment: Thanks @lawyeR! But I don't understand it completely...what do you mean with the same values? It is not logical to obtain different results after different random initializations?

Comment: Cool! Now it works (or at least I don't have errors with som training). Thank you @MarcoSandri.

Answer (score 0):

Rlen argument accepts a single value, i.e. in your code it should be `rlen=100` (default) or `rlen=1000`